# Mutli-level nesting of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I want to write a function that takes a JavaScript object as input with selected attributes of the object and return a modified indented/grouping structure as shown below.

```
var s1 = {
    "f01":{},
    "f02":{},
    "f03":{},
    "f04":{},
    "f05":{}
};


var s2 = indent_items(s1, ["f02", "f03", "f04"]);
```

s2 should be structured this way

```
{
    "f01":{},
    "d01":{
        "f02":{},
        "f03":{},
        "f04":{}
    },
    "f05":{}
};


var s3 = indent_items(s2, ["f03", "f04"]);
```

s3 should be structured this way

```
{
    "f01":{},
    "d01":{
        "f02":{},
        "d02":{
            "f03":{},
            "f04":{}
        },
    },
    "f05":{}
};
```

and so on going deep many levels. How to achieve this?

Comment: Suppose you now use `var s4 = indent_items(s3, ["f03", "f04"]);`, what's the output?

Comment: What did you try ? What are your difficulties ?

Comment: There are no built in features in JavaScript to achieve this, you will have to come up with your own algorithm finding and replacing object properties with nested objects.

Comment: @Elric, f03, f04 should indent further to "d03"

Comment: from where does `var s2 = indent_items(s1, ["f02", "f03", "f04"]);` know that `d01` should be used?

Comment: And what would happen in case of `var s4 = indent_items(s3, ["f01", "f04"]);`, this is interesting? You should post more edge cases like this one.

Comment: @julestruong I iterated through the input structure recursively and trying to push the selected attributes to a newly created object, but it's is confusing to work for multiple levels

Comment: @ Nina Scholz  it's just a counter..  "d"+counter

Comment: @dfsq You can consider this as having a folder inside a folder with no other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution features a recursion for the indentation.

- `Object.keys` for getting all keys of the object
- `Array.prototype.forEach` for iteration over the keys

```js
function indent_items(obj, array) {

    function recursion(o, r) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (~array.indexOf(k)) {
                r[id] = r[id] || {};
                r[id][k] = o[k];
                return;
            }
            if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                r[k] = r[k] || {}
                recursion(o[k], r[k]);
                return;
            }
            r[k] = o[k];
        });
    }

    var result = {},
        id = 'd' + ('0' + ++count).slice(-2);

    recursion(obj, result);
    return result;
}

var count = 0,
    s1 = { "f01": {}, "f02": {}, "f03": {}, "f04": {}, "f05": {} },
    s2 = indent_items(s1, ["f02", "f03", "f04"]),
    s3 = indent_items(s2, ["f03", "f04"]);

document.write('<pre>s1:' + JSON.stringify(s1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>s2:' + JSON.stringify(s2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>s3:' + JSON.stringify(s3, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Can this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)` be avoided? Let's say my f03 object has a *function*. Will it be restored to f03, back after `stringify` and `parse`?

Comment: yes it can, please see edit, but it holds the reference to the old object, which i had prevented with the copy of the object.

Comment: Awesome! your solution worked for me (with a few minor changes). Thank you!